# Is there a way to embed the filter UI into a map (for the user to use)?

Tags: carto

Is there a way to embed the dynamic filter UI into a map for the user to use? I want them to be able to filter data in the same way that I can do it from my UI.

Is the first map on the following page just a "photoshopped" image? Or is there a way to let the user filter the data on their end?
http://cartodb.com/analyze

Comment: For the moment (2/Jun/2014) we don't have that feature. The image in the webpage is indeed a "photoshopped" image to show schematically what the UI can do. In any case  I'm pretty sure we will work on that since it's a frequently requested feature but unfortunately I couldn't give you a date for this

Comment: Also, the CartoDB team will be happy to help you with that implementation using CartoDB.js if you are into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, there's not a built-in option to add filtering capability (besides the layer selector) in the embedded map.

The trick is to use CartoDB.js that allows you to interact with the maps and the data. For example, you can create some HTML elements and assign to them some specific functions to be applied to the map.

In [this detailed tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html) you can check how some buttons are created and each of them runs a query in your data to update the map with the results according to the button you use to filter.